# Multiselectpicklist inlineeditsupport double click shows disrupted popup

Tags: visualforce, javascript, jquery, multi-select, inlineeditsupport

I have a multiselectpicklist within apex:inlineeditsupport shown on a Visualforce table. When double clicked on it, the pop up window is corrupted as shown. I found that the issue is because of the width being automatically set. How to fix this, please help me out as i'm not a js expert.

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The select box takes the width of the largest option available. Ideally, you can reduce the length of the options or choose a more user-friendly UI interface to show these options to a user.

---

You can add this in your VF page to control the width but this is not something I would recommend if you are designing for mobile and tablets as well.

```
<style>
    .multiSelectPicklistRow select {
        max-width: 300px;
    }
</style>
```

---

Simpler option:

```
<form method="post" action="/Tests/Post/">      
    <fieldset>      
        <legend>What is Your Favorite Pet?</legend>      
        <input type="checkbox" name="favorite_pet" value="Cats">Cats<br>      
        <input type="checkbox" name="favorite_pet" value="Dogs">Dogs<br>      
        <input type="checkbox" name="favorite_pet" value="Birds">Birds<br>      
        <br>      
        <input type="submit" value="Submit now" />      
    </fieldset>      
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks @Manjit5190. That did the trick. Any suggestions on your recommendation to choose more user friendly UI to show options?

Comment: Well, a checkbox in front of each option would be great to start with, something as simple as this https://html5-tutorial.net/try.html#pre4

Comment: Ok, did you share any code in the above url coz it take me to an empty editor

Comment: Yes, I did . :)  Updated the answer

Comment: cool! thank you Manjit :)